# Finding the gradient of a function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A function $f=f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives , and assume that maximal directional derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is equal to $100$ and is attained in the direction towards $(3,-4)$ , we need to find $\nabla f$ at $(0,0)$.

What I did :

Let $\nabla f = xi+yj$ , now maximal directional derivative is given to be $100$ so , $|\nabla f|=100$ , => $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=100$ ,

Also , the directional vector "$u$" is $u=3i-4j$ ,

Now , $u.\nabla f=|u||\nabla f|cos\theta$ , where , $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla f$ and $u$ ,

So for maximal directional value $\theta = 0$ and thus we get ,

$u.\nabla f=|u||\nabla f|$

=>$(3i-4j).(xi+yj)=5.100$

Thus we get two equations in two variables $x$ and $y$ , which gives $\nabla f$.

Is the above solution correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You know $\nabla f(0,0)=k(3,-4)$ for some $k\in \mathbb R$

which just means that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=3k$ and

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=-4k$

You also are given that

$3\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)-4\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=100$

Solve for $k$:

$9k+16k=100\Rightarrow k=25$.

Now substitute for $k$ to obtain

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=75$ and

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=-100$